# Regular Expression Ignore Question Mark

Tags: regex

How do I ignore the question mark in a regular expression?

For example:

```
xxx.com/supplier.php?id=500
```

I want to write something like:

```
xxx.com/supplier.php?id=.*
```

Therefore I need to ignore the question mark.

Comment: Escape the question mark and dots so that they are treated as literals. See [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions).

Comment: use the escape character. for majority of syntaxes is \ so `\?` would match a literal `?`

Answer (score 0):

You would normally escape with the \ character, and also this applies to the / character  [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fK3jQ4/1)

```
xxx.com\/supplier.php\?id=.*
```